# ASP.NET MVC Image Button Inside HTML.BeginForm Problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 2 portal. My requirement is something like below:

```
<form action = "mvc2proj/ControllerName/ActionName/1234" method="post">
  CheckBox 1 to select first item
  CheckBox 2 to select second item
  CheckBox 3 to select third item
  CheckBox 4 to select fourth item
  "Buy Now" image button
</form>
```

I am using HTML.BeginForm() to generate "form" element as:

```
<%Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ContrllerName", new {id=1234}, FormMethod="Post");%>
```

When I use HTML submit button, I am able to get form values on "ActionName" action of the "ControllerName" controller. But since it should be an image button rathar than a regular HTML submit button.

So how will I be able to use an IMAGE BUTTON inside HTML.BeginForm()?

Answer (score 3):

This should work. Your form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction", "Home")){ %>

<%=Html.CheckBox("Item1") %>
<%=Html.CheckBox("Item2") %>
<%=Html.CheckBox("Item3") %>
<%=Html.CheckBox("Item4") %>

<button name="button"><img src="yourimage.png" /></button>

<% } %>
```

And the corresponding action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult MyAction(string Item1, string Item2, string Item3, string Item4)
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Yes...You are right. I have already seen this solution. But intellisense does not show SubmitImage helper function. I am using MVC 2 and my development environment is VS2010.

Comment: My bad. Updated my answer to something that works. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why don't we use input type=image HTML submit button? It works for me.